# C++ and C# Speed Test - Strange Result

Tags: c#, c++, execution

For my new project which needs high speed calculation, I am trying to chose between C++ and C#. I've always heard that C# is reasonable in speed. I knew that it is slower that C and C++, but my exception was that the difference is not huge! So I wrote two codes in C++ and C# to test them myself.

**The result was around 5:09 to 5:55 second for C++ versus 11408 to 11960 second for C#.**

So is something wrong with my codes, or this is what it really is? 
Here is my C++ code:

```
clock_t tStart = clock();
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("log.txt");
std::string pi;

int limit = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
        {
            double val = sin(i *i + j *j + k *k);
            pi = std::to_string(val);
            myfile << pi<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
myfile.close();
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
getchar();
return 0;
```

and here is my C# code:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
string path = @"c:\log.txt";
int limit = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
     {
          for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
          {
                double val = Math.Sin(i *i + j *j + k *k);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(val.ToString("F6"));
                }
          }
     }
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.Write(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

My OS is Win7 64bit.
Thanks in advance for your time.

@EDIT: why changing 
    double val = Math.Sin(i *i + j *j + k *k);
to 
    double val = Math.Sin(i^2 + j^2 + k^2);
in C#, produces totally different answers?

Comment: Notice that you are opening file inside of the loop - unlike in your C++ version.

Comment: wow, yes you are right. I changed that and now the result for C# is **44 millisecond** which is unbelievable. So what is wrong with C++ now?

Comment: @M0HS3N Are you sure you are compiling with optimization enabled?

Comment: You are running the code in Debug mode instead or Release mode

Comment: I removed std::string and it is much better now: 700 ms. In release mode it is 160 ms which is much better, but still slower than C# which is 44 ms. I did not do any optimisation neither for C++ nor C#.

Comment: Why are you doing `to_string?` Why not just `myfile << val << '\n';`?

Comment: Your question has been answered. Don't keep editing the question until you have all your answers, accept one of the ones you got and post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            //...
        }          
    }
}
```

Your results are not surprising - you are opening file and creating and disposing `StreamWriter` at the every iteration. You should create it once:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
        {
                //...   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already corrected this, and now the result for C# is 44 millisecond which is great. So now what is wrong with my C++ code?

Comment: @M0HS3N Don't use std::to_string,  myfile << val <<"\n"; would be enough.

Comment: I removed std::string and it is much better now: 700 ms. In release mode it is 160 ms which is much better, but still slower than C# which is 44 ms. any other idea?

Comment: @M0HS3N Try the C-style I/O, which would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference in your test is that for the C++ one, you open and Close the file outside the loop, which means it only happen 1 time.

In your C# test, you will open the file, do file seek to the end and then Close it for every iteration. This will be a huge time sink.

You should instead move the Creation of the streamwriter to be above your loop, and then Close it after you exit the loop.

I'm refering to the code

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(val.ToString("F6"));
        }
```